# How to Check third party jquery file fully load

Tags: jquery, performance, pageload, load-time

I want to check any third party jquery file load 100% or not. Also, jquery file in minify mode. Please tell me, how to check load jquery file after call script.

Comment: Please show us some relevant code or what you have tried.

Comment: Pls check my code which i tried.
myextScript.src = 'https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myextScript);
      window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
      window.setTimeout(function ()
      {
          if ( 'pubads' in window) {               
     Here my add google ads code.
      $('#responce').html('<h3>Adds Loads Successfully !');
          } else {
             $('#responce').html('<h3>Adds not Loaded. Because js file not loaded with in time !');
          }
      }, 2000);

Comment: I am not able to get third party js file function.If you have a better idea then plz share with me.